# Unable to install bcompiler in centos 5.8 getting error unable to unpack /tmp/bcompiler

Tags: php, linux, centos, pecl, centos5

Unable to install bcompiler in centos 5.8 getting error unable to unpack /tmp/bcompiler

Command i am performing :-

> root@linux# pecl install bcompiler starting to download...
>   bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz (57,247 bytes) ...Downloading and than downloaded
>   ...
>
> Error: unable to unpack /tmp/tmpASDWss/bcompiler-.1.0.2.tgz

I google few times but unable to find Solution, seems like no one got this error..

I have encoded my phpscript from bcompiler in my ubuntuLinux and i uploaded it to my server.. of centos..

Please note i am using bcompiler for the first time, so i though, i might not need bcompiler but as you might have expected page fails :(

So i thought i need to install bcompiler in my server too... so i started installing but failing. Please Explain me am I doing anything wrong.

Can i get any help please
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Simply Download file from http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler

Action :- Just make sure, you read output, At one point it will tell you where bcompiler.so 
file has been save.

```
root@linux# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz
root@linux# tar -xvf bcompiler-1.0.2.tgz
root@linux# phpize
root@linux# ./configure
root@linux# make
root@linux# make install
root@linux# make test
```

If nothing has gone wrong than bcompiler.so file must have been placed to 'ext' directory..

Now Start using your bcompiler if everything was OK :)